# The two devices which facilitate storage over a network

Tags: networking, raid, database, storage, network-storage

I have been ask for specifically 'THE TWO' devices which facilitate storage over a network, powerful in addressing, failures and redundancy.

Could anyone figure out which devices these are? It seems a bit too general, and I haven't got a clue.

Comment: There's a lot more than two devices involved in either networking, or storage. I don't even know what "powerful in addressing" could possibly mean.

Comment: Neither do I, which is why I'm at a loss :/ Could it maybe refer to RAID?

Comment: This sounds like some kind of riddle, not a technical question.

Comment: It's a homework question actually. The question is literally asking me to describe the two devices which facilitate storage over a network

Comment: I say go for the target and the initiator.

Comment: Voting to close, because it's not a query raised in a professional capacity, as required by the faq.

Comment: and the close-it-down rage begins again :/

Comment: I'd go with 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

maybe someone had [san](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) and [nas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) on her/his mind?

Comment: Your teacher's question is terribly worded, but I think @pQd's answer is probably "right". There are two main types of network attached storage, SAN and NAS.